# Lync API - CaptureVideoWindow and RenderVideoWindow are Null

Tags: c#, sdk, video-streaming, lync

I have downloaded the SDK for Lync 2013 and am having a problem with the code sample found in `AudioVideoConversation.csproj`.  This project is supposed to demonstrate the use of Audio/Video conversations through the Lync API.  I am having trouble getting the video portion to function in the sample application.  The problem is in this method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the video state changes.
    /// 
    /// Will show Incoming/Outgoing video based on the channel state.
    /// </summary>
    void videoChannel_StateChanged(object sender, ChannelStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //posts the execution into the UI thread
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            //updates the status bar with the video channel state
            toolStripStatusLabelVideoChannel.Text = e.NewState.ToString();


            //*****************************************************************************************
            //                              Video Content
            //
            // The video content is only available when the Lync client is running in UISuppressionMode.
            //
            // The video content is not directly accessible as a stream. It's rather available through
            // a video window that can de drawn in any panel or window.
            //
            // The outgoing video is accessible from videoChannel.CaptureVideoWindow
            // The window will be available when the video channel state is either Send or SendReceive.
            // 
            // The incoming video is accessible from videoChannel.RenderVideoWindow
            // The window will be available when the video channel state is either Receive or SendReceive.
            //
            //*****************************************************************************************

            //if the outgoing video is now active, show the video (which is only available in UI Suppression Mode)
            if ((e.NewState == ChannelState.Send 
                || e.NewState == ChannelState.SendReceive) && videoChannel.CaptureVideoWindow != null)
            {
                //presents the video in the panel
                ShowVideo(panelOutgoingVideo, videoChannel.CaptureVideoWindow);
            }

            //if the incoming video is now active, show the video (which is only available in UI Suppression Mode)
            if ((e.NewState == ChannelState.Receive 
                || e.NewState == ChannelState.SendReceive) && videoChannel.RenderVideoWindow != null)
            {
                //presents the video in the panel
                ShowVideo(panelIncomingVideo, videoChannel.RenderVideoWindow);
            }

        }));
    }
```

The variables `videoChannel.CaptureVideoWindow` and `videoChannel.RenderVideoWindow` are always null (please note that, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313507/lync-videowindows-of-avmodality-videochannel-are-null-after-successfully-callin), the `videoChannel` variable is NOT null).

Some things you should know:

1. I am running Lync in UI Suppression mode (achieved by adding the registry key `UISuppressionMode` [DWORD] as 1 at location HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync)
2. The audio portion of the sample works perfectly
3. The sample is actually *sending* my video stream to the remote party successfully
4. When the conversation is done setting up, `e.NewState == ChannelState.SendReceive` evaluates to `true`
5. I am working in Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft Lync 2013

Comment: Not yet.  Tabled the project in the meantime.  =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fired up an old demo (January 2014 time frame) I built and everything worked fine.  I then installed the latest version of the SDK and ran the sample and sure enough, I had the same issue.

The issue is due to an exception when you try to set the owner of the Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.AudioVideo.VideoWindow.

It turns out, there was a change in how permissions are handled for taking over this window.  **The *"fix"* for now is to place the application into the user folder of the account running the program.**  I tried this and it does, indeed work.

Here is the offending from ConversationWindow.cs:line 1128...

```
//sets the properties required for the native video window to draw itself
videoWindow.Owner = videoPanel.Handle.ToInt32();
```

Here is the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Uc.VideoWindowClass.set_Owner(Int32 Owner)    at
>   Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.AudioVideo.VideoWindow.set_Owner(Int32
>   value)    at AudioVideoConversation.ConversationWindow.ShowVideo(Panel
>   videoPanel, VideoWindow videoWindow) in c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Office
>   2013\LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation\Conversation\ConversationWindow.cs:line
>   1128

References:
[UISuppression Video Issues](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/07ee768a-d308-4dad-95ea-837c95bcadd2/uisuppression-videowindowowner-raises-generic-com-exception-0x800706f7?forum=communicatorsdk)

> A clarification from the Lync API engineering team: The unauthorized
>   access (or COM) exception that  you may get when assigning an owner
>   handle to the VideoWindow is resolved by copying the sample project
>   out of the \Program Files(x86)... folder to a user folder. Compile
>   and run the project in the user folder and you will not get an
>   exception.

Comment: So, I went to reproduce the problem today by running the sample application in its default directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation` and I can't repeat it...  =(  It works just fine for me without having to move the location of the sample application.  What's going on here??  lol

Comment: It might have something to do with the owner of the directory.  Are you (your account) the owner of C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation?

Comment: I definitely have full permissions (including "Full Control" and "Take Ownership") but I had the same level of permissions when I tried this last May.  *In fact!*, this is the same installation of the SDK I used when I posted the question.  I opened the same copy of the project, ran it the same way, under the same account.  I can't fathom what could have changed.

Comment: Hrmmm... Now I'm baffled.  I just tried with the EXE in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation\bin\Debug and it works here too.  I'm going to look into this a little deeper and get back to you.

Comment: Did you have to install the SDK afresh?  If so, had you rebooted your PC before repeating the problem?  I wonder if it's something as simple as that.  I'd be sad if it was.

Comment: BTW - This issue is referenced in the readme.txt file for the sample.
..."Running the sample
------------------
1. Copy the AudioVideoConversation folder to a folder outside of Program Files.
 - The sample should run in the same privilege level of Lync. 
 - Compiling it from Program Files prevents Lync from being able to draw video in the conversation window of this sample."...

Comment: It works for me even when I delete the DLL's.  lol @ the ReadMe - I guess I should probably read that before complaining next time.  Alrighty, well, this is as much as I'd hoped to know about it.  Marking you as the answer!